# Angular how to access values from Json Array from firebase doc

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire

```
this.currentUser$=this.afs.doc('users/'+this.authState.uid).valueChanges().pipe();
```

When I am using in component.html like

```
{{ currentUser$|async|json}}
```

I am getting it like below:

```
{
  "photoUrl": "",
  "password": "",
  "mobileVerified": true,
  "id": "izoNRvk0moN579KqfQ1cVqNvpZJ2",
  "phone": "5544663311",
  "email": "admin@example.com",
  "name": "Rob B",
  "userRole": "admin"
}
```

Now for example I want to access just `email` or `userRole`, how I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

Set the value in `pipe`.

```
currentUser$: Observable<User>;
currentUser?: User;

 :

 this.currentUser$=this.afs.doc('users/'+this.authState.uid).valueChanges().pipe(
  tap( value => {
    this.currentUser = value;
  })
 );
```

Then you can access each property.

```
{{currentUser?.email}}
{{currentUser?.userRole}}
```

Comment: Hi, somehow I was not able to make it work. I am getting errors like: `(property) HeaderComponent.currentUser?: User | undefined
Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<User>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, User>'.
  Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
    Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<User>'.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'User'.ts(2345)`

Answer (score 0):

I used the suggestions [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md) to get the values from single document from firebase collection, but had to make a little modification for `currentUser<User>` to `currentUser<User | undefined>` and it works perfectly.

```
private userDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<User>;
currentUser: Observable<User | undefined>;
```

and in constructor:

```
this.userDoc = afs.doc<User>('users/'+this.docId);
this.currentUser = this.userDoc.valueChanges();
```

and in component.html I can access this like

```
{{(currentUser|async)?.email}}
{{(currentUser|async)?.userRole}}
```